# Is it possible to use the data attributes of parent elements?

Tags: css, html

Given markup like this:

```
<article data-text="foo">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et...</p>
</article>
```

is it possible to use the data-text attribute in CSS on the children of article?

```
h2:before {
  content: attr(data-text) ': ';
}
```

Comment: Even if you could, it's **not implemented** in all browsers, so I don't recommend you to use this. You want to add ``data-text`` content before ``h2`` content ?

Comment: @JérémyHalin Yes the data-text is supposed to be added to the h2 but other elements as well and I would prefer it no to clutter the markup by adding it to every relevant element since they all share the same parent. And it is implemented in effectively all browsers, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: Well I don't think it's possible to get ``data`` attribute of parent with **CSS only**. In my opinion you need javascript.

Comment: Simply..."NO". There is no parent selector and so equally, the parent's attribute cannot be selected and inserted into the child's pseudo-element. You need javascript.